# Regarding custom metrics application insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I have a scenario where I'm getting custom metrics thru an application. I want to create alerts based on thresholds and days of the week. Is there any way I can integrate the metadata in some storage and compare the metrics based on that? For example, I have message count metrics in the application, and if on Monday the message count is less than 100 or more than 200 I should get an alert. It varies on the day of the week. I have to monitor almost 250 custom metrics.

I tried implementing custom logs in Log analytics but I have a challenge in case if I want to change the thresholds then I need to drop the custom table and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [AnuragSingh-MSFT | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/anuragsingh-msft/). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> Using a combination of both [**dayofweek()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dayofweekfunction) and [**case()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/casefunction) functions, the resultant query itself can contain the threshold based on the day-of-week. Therefore, in future if the threshold changes, you will only have to edit the `case` statement and this solution also does not require additional storage/custom table.

```
let day = dayofweek(now());
let threshold = case(day == 1d, 5m,  //threshold for Monday is 5 minutes
day == 2d, 2m, //threshold for Tuesday is 2 minutes
day == 3d, 5s, //threshold for Wednesday is 5 seconds
10m); //threshold for any other day is 10 minutes.

Heartbeat
| summarize LastHeartbeat=max(TimeGenerated) by Computer
| where LastHeartbeat < ago(threshold)
```

Reference: [Regarding custom metrics application insights - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/762717/regarding-custom-metrics-application-insights.html)